# Regular expression for performing task being done by string functions

Tags: c#, regex

The below code is performing following functionality which I intend to integrate into larger application.

1. Splitting large input string `input` by dot (.) character wherever it
   occurs in input string.
2. Storing the splitted substrings into array `result[]`;
3. In the foreach loop , a substring is matched for occurrence of
   **keyword**.
4. If match occurs , starting from position of this matched substring in original input string , upto **300 characters** are to be printed.

   ```
       string[] result = input.Split('.');
       foreach (string str in result)
       {

           //Console.WriteLine(str);
           Match m = Regex.Match(str, keyword);
           if (m.Success)
           {
               int start = input.IndexOf(str);
               if ((input.Length - start) < 300)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(start, input.Length - start));
                   break;
               }
               else
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(start, 300)); 
                   break;
               }
           }
   ```

The input is in fact large amount of text and I think this should be done by regular expression. Being a novice ,I am not able to put everything together using a regular expressions .

Match keyword. `Match m = Regex.Match(str, keyword);`

300 characters starting from dot (.)  i.e starting from matched sentence , print 300 characters `"^.\w{0,300}"`

What I intend to do is :

1. Search for keyword in input text.
2. Just as a match is found , **start from the sentence containing the
   keyword** and print upto 300 characters from input string.

   How should I proceed ? Please help .

Comment: At the moment you are searching each sentence for `keyword` twice - once in `Regex.Match`, once in `IndexOf`. Either use `m.Index` instead of `input.IndexOf(str)`, or remove `m` completely, move `start` outside the `if` block and change the condition to `start > -1`. (If you're literally matching a word, I'd use `IndexOf` in preference to the regex.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, all you need to do is find your `keyword` and capture all that follows until you find first dot or reach maximum number of characters:

```
@"keyword([^\.]{0,300})"
```

C# code:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"keyword([^\.]{0,300})");

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(input))
{
   var result = match.Groups[1].Value;
   
   // work with the result
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out.. I used ^ to signify start of sentence . Can You please explain how should I reach the sentence containing the word and extract substring using above regular expression

Comment: I have completely changed my answer to reflect your keyword requirement.. Does it fit?

Comment: It is now successfully starting from sentence containing keyword but the string being printed terminates as soon as next full stop is encountered . It should continue onwards upto 300 characters or till end of input string is reached .

Comment: Then go with @"keyword(.{0,300})"

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
(?<=\.?)([\w\s]{0,300}keyword.*?)(?=\.)
```

explain:

> ***`(?= subexpression)`*** Zero-width positive lookahead assertion.
>
> ***`(?<= subexpression)`*** Zero-width positive lookbehind assertion.
>
> ***`*?`*** Matches the previous element zero or more times, but as few times as possible.

and a simple code:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, 
                                      @"(?<=\.?)([\w\s]{0,300}print.*?)(?=\.)"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ....It is now successfully starting from sentence containing keyword but the string being printed terminates as soon as next full stop is encountered . It should continue onwards upto 300 characters or till end of input string is reached .